# Can the plane be covered by fewer than continuum many injective curves?

Tags: set-theory, plane-curves

**Background:** The plane cannot be covered by fewer than continuum many lines. The simplest proof I know goes like this:

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a collection of lines in the plane, $|\mathcal{A}|<\mathfrak{c}$. Take a line $l$ not in $\mathcal{A}$. Every line in $\mathcal{A}$ intersects $l$ in at most one point, but there are continuum many points on $\mathcal{l}$. So in fact $\bigcup\mathcal{A}$ misses continuum many points on $l$, and in particular cannot equal $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Note that we don't use any heavy machinery here (or any machinery at all, really) and it also does not depend on how the continuum hypothesis works out.

**Question:** Does the same hold for injective continuous curves? Specifically, can the plane be covered by fewer than continuum many injective curves, i.e. injective continuous maps $\alpha:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$? (Note injectivity is necessary here due to space-filling curves.) <s>The answer is affirmative under CH, but I'm only able to do this using high powered arguments (e.g. noting that the image of each curve has measure zero and the union of countably many null sets is null). But it's consistent for the union of uncountably many but fewer than continuum null sets to have positive measure.</s> (The answer is still affirmative under CH but the argument I just gave doesn't work, see first comment.)

This feels like the sort of question that has been asked before (and in this case either proven true or shown independent, probably in a similar way to cardinal characteristics of the continuum) but I've found it difficult to find references. Thanks!

Comment: Nice problem! But the image of an injective continuous map $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ need *not* be null - see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood_curve). That said, it is true that $\mathsf{CH}$ gives a positive answer to the question: any continuous injective map from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ misses some compact set with nonempty interior, so by a descending sequence of compact sets argument we can't cover $\mathbb{R}^2$ with countably many injective continuous maps $[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$. Now use $\sigma$-compactness of $\mathbb{R}$ to get the result you want.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yikes, and this whole time I thought you could just wrap any curve in an arbitrarily skinny cylinder. But the Osgood curve makes it so the cylinder doesn't actually cover less area as you shrink it! My meager human intuition is humbled again.

Comment: @bof No idea offhand, but the ideas from [this old argument of Ashutosh](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184562/the-continuum-hypothesis-for-packing-shapes-without-overlapping) might be relevant.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Do you mean to suggest that the image of an injective curve $[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is nowhere dense? It seems like this is necessary for your proof to work, though I don’t see how to show it. If this is true, then Martin’s Axiom implies the result, since a union of $\kappa$ closed nowhere-dense sets is nowhere dense assuming $MA(\kappa)$.

Comment: @MarkSaving I don't believe I need that at all. I'm just using the following. If $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous, then its image is compact, hence in particular closed. We know its image isn't all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so pick some $a\not\in im(f)$. By closedness of $im(f)$ there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that the closed ball around $a$ of radius $\epsilon$ is disjoint from $im(f)$. We can iterate this appropriately.

Comment: @bof Yes, this is what I meant (with meager meaning having an empty interior). Obviously we have $\bigcup\limits_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \{q\}$ as a counterexample of the “nowhere dense” claim.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, the claim that the map misses a compact set with nonempty interior is straightforward. But how are you getting the nested descending sequence of compact sets needed for the proof? You can get a second such compact set for the second curve, but there is no reason the second compact set should lie within the first.

Comment: @MarkSaving I think you just iterate the argument within the interior of the first compact set. The intersection of the second curve with the interior of the first compact set is closed in the interior and cannot be all of the interior, and so you repeat the argument to get the second compact set with nonempty interior within the first. Even better if they don't intersect at all.

Comment: @planecover Your argument doesn’t make use of the curve being injective, which means it must be wrong since there are space-filling curves. I don’t see why the intersection of the image of the curve with an open set would be compact.

Comment: @MarkSaving Ok, I guess I should say the intersection of the curve and compact set is compact. And then we just have to show it does not contain the entire interior, which is where injectivity is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's consistent with ZFC [that $\operatorname{cov}(\mathcal B)\lt2^{\aleph_0}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicho%C5%84%27s_diagram), i.e., $\mathbb R$ is the union of fewer than continuum  many meager sets.

Suppose $\mathbb R$ is the union of $\kappa$ meager sets. It follows that $\mathbb R$ is the union of $\kappa$ compact nowhere dense sets $A_i$, which are of course totally disconnected, so that $\mathbb R^2$ is the union of $\kappa$ totally disconnected compact sets $A_i\times A_j$. By the [Moore–Kline theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denjoy%E2%80%93Riesz_theorem), each of those totally disconnected compact sets is covered by an *arc* in the plane, i.e., a homeomorph of $[0,1]$. Hence $\mathbb R^2$ is the union of $\kappa$ arcs.